# Is there an algorithm to work out the max number of small shapes you can tesselate inside a larger one?

Tags: algorithm

Consider the following 4x4 grid and L-shaped tile (made up of squares the same size as those in the grid). It is obvious that the most number of L-shapes one can fit on the grid without overlapping is 5. Is there an algorithm that can find this number in general?

[image]

Comment: This answers your question ? : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tiling-problem-using-divide-and-conquer-algorithm/

Comment: Aside: I don't think tesselate is correct, that's infinitely repeatable patterns

Comment: I don't think that there is a much better method than brute force in general. Some tilings can be quite irregular.

Comment: It is obvious that the ratio of the area of the large shape over that of the small one is an upper bound. But not necessarily tight.

Comment: @HMH1013 -- thanks for that link. It almost solves it, but gives me enough to get my teeth into. Need to think how I can generalise it to rectangular grids not of dimensions 2^k x 2^k.